# Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch | windows | Xampp

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.2 where I am getting follwing error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php:665
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(665): Exception->__construct(NULL, 502)
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php(320): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\react\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Future\CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\ezimuel\ringphp\src\Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\F in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection.php on line 665
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/403356013159"}]}}
E:\xampp\htdocs\magento>
```

prior installing Magento I installed Elasticsearch 7.9.3 and ElasticSearch running fine on http://localhost:9200. here is what I get

```
{
  "name" : "SYS-202101",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "a479a2a7fce0389512d6a9361301708b92dff667",
    "build_date" : "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Following is the command i used to install Magento 2.4.2

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento/" --backend-frontname="admin" --session-save="files" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="Admin" --admin-email="admin@domaine.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin-123" --language=en_US --currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Paris --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you set the parameters in Magento settings. If not, go to STORES > settings > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search. Set host=host port=9002. Disable authentication.

Comment: @Mr.Kovalski I am installing fresh magento in Xampp, so where can i find Stores > settings, and i run installation with `--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0` do i need to change anything?

Comment: Yeah, you said your port is 9002. Use that in the install command instead.
`--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9002 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0`

Comment: BTW if you installed Magento already, check app/etc/env.php value of the front name is where the admin panel is located.

Comment: @Mr.Kovalski can you please suggest me installation command.

Comment: You are using it right but change the port to be like in my last comment. But honestly, if you can dual boot Linux or try it on windows with WSL this is a much better DEV environment: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

Comment: @Mr.Kovalski sorry for my stupidity while writing this question. Elasticsearch is running on port:9200 only , I have updated this question.